# How to design layout of JSON Array inside another JSON Array in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-layout, android-json

I want to set Json array data inside another json array data into XML Layout but how is design I am new in android developing Please help me solve this problem my layout is here:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/linear_layout_02"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage_02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvName_02"
            android:text="@string/samsung_galaxy"
            android:textColor="#166CED"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvId_02"
            android:textColor="#D64530"
            android:text="@string/id_30"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvmanufacturer_02"
            android:textColor="#D64530"
            android:text="@string/manufacturer"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvmodel_02"
            android:textColor="#D64530"
            android:text="@string/model"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvreward_02"
            android:textColor="#D64530"
            android:text="@string/reward"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvpoints_02"
            android:textColor="#D64530"
            android:text="@string/point"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPrice_02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/price"
            android:textColor="#D64530"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRating_02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#D64530"
            android:text="@string/Rating_0" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSpecial_02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#D64530"
            android:text="@string/special" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDescription_02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#009A57"
    android:text="@string/description"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvhref_02"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

[I have JSON Data link is here](http://opencart.codeniques.com/myshop/?route=feed/web_api/product&id=30&key=test123)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the syntax and semantics of JSON libary -

https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples

https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples

This library is by default included in Android SDK

Comment: Also, check the official [json documentation](http://www.json.org/) it is simpler than it looks. Just add the info as {"arrayName":[{"internalArray":values},{"anotherInternalArray":values2}]}